# Distance calculation between 2 land points in c #

Tags: c#, latitude-longitude

with the function below I calculate the distance between 2 land points by passing latitude (a), latitude (b), longitude (a), longitude (b), and performing the calculation in kilometers with the formula given below but the result is not correct, how can I solve it?

**Code C#:**

```
public static double CalcoloDistinzaFra2PuntiTerrestri(double LatA, double LonA, double LatB, double LonB)
{
    double tot = 0;
    const double R = 6371;
    const double pigreco = 3.1415927;
    double lat_alfa, lat_beta;
    double lon_alfa, lon_beta;
    double fi, p;
    lat_alfa = pigreco * LatA / 180;
    lat_beta = pigreco * LatB / 180;
    lon_alfa = pigreco * LonA / 180;
    lon_beta = pigreco * LonB / 180;
    fi = Math.Abs(lon_alfa - lon_beta);
    p = Math.Acos(Sin(lat_beta) * Sin(lat_alfa) + Cos(lat_beta) * Cos(lat_alfa) * Cos(fi));
    tot = p * R;
    return tot;
}
```

Comment: Microsoft provides the `GeoCoordinate` class which may be of use. ( https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.device.location.geocoordinate?view=netframework-4.8 )

Comment: Please use the `GeoCoordinate` class as @KDecker recommended, as it has the [Haversine equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haversine_formula) already implemented to do this.

Comment: And please review the [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) guide, because your question would appear to a *busy colleague* as asking to do it all for you. Also see @EricLippert's answer, since he *literally* answered your question.

Answer (score 10):

> how can I solve it?

You solve problems in computer programming by breaking down the program into smaller and smaller parts, to discover which part is incorrect.

You know that the calculation is incorrect, which means that you must know what the correct answer is. That's great; that's how you will find the problem:

- Work out **by hand** what you believe is the correct value of each expression in your program.
- Then write a program to compute **just each expression in turn**.
- Then compare that program to your prediction of what the correct value should be for that step.
- At some point the program and your by-hand computation will differ.  **That's where the bug is**.

Answer (score 0):

You are using a wrong formula, you should use [Haversine formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haversine_formula) as @Elaskanator said. ALso use `Math.PI` instead of 3.1415927.